# What is the difference between `InstallPixels()` and `SetPixels()` in `SkiaSharp.SKBitmap`?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm not clear on how `SKBitmap.InstallPixels()` and `SKBitmap.SetPixels()` work. Here's the documentation for one of each method (there are several method overloads):

```
// Summary:
//     Installs the specified pixels into the bitmap.
//
// Parameters:
//   info:
//     The image information describing the pixels.
//
//   pixels:
//     The pixels to install.
//
// Returns:
//     Returns true on success, or false on failure. If there was an error, the bitmap
//     will be set to empty.
public bool InstallPixels(SKImageInfo info, IntPtr pixels);

// Summary:
//     Replaces the current pixel address for the bitmap.
//
// Parameters:
//   pixels:
//     The new pixel address.
public void SetPixels(IntPtr pixels);
```

My guess is that `InstallPixels()` copies the data from the `IntPtr` to a local byte array, whereas `SetPixels()` makes the passed `IntPtr` the byte array to use.

If my assumption is correct, does that mean that if I want to use `InstallPixels()` I need to first call `TryAllocPixels()` to create the internal byte array? If I want to use `SetPixels()`, do I need to manually dispose of the byte array or does it get disposed when the `SKBitmap` is disposed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, this is probably two years too late to be useful, but I've found this question popping up in my searches once again so I'll furnish an answer in the hopes it might be useful for someone.

- `InstallPixels` is capable of completely changing the image. It takes as arguments either a separate `SkImageInfo` and pointer to a pixel array, or an `SkPixmap` which bundles the image info and pixel array pointer together. Because it can update the image info, `InstallPixels` can be used to change the size, pixel format or colour space of an image. You can freely use `InstallPixels` on an empty image created with `new SkBitmap()`.

  `InstallPixels` also optionally takes a delegate that will be invoked on the supplied pixel array pointer when the bitmap is disposed of. This can be used to do things like unpin arrays, release GC handles, free memory on the non-GC heap and so on. This lets you pass ownership of a memory buffer to an `SkBitmap` instance, and not have to worry about keeping it alive or cleaning it up yourself.
- By comparison, `SetPixels` takes *only* a pointer to a pixel array. You cannot change the size, pixel format or colour space of the bitmap, so the pointed-to array should have the same size and layout as the bitmap you're modifying.

  `SetPixels` doesn't take a release delegate. This means that responsibility for keeping the pointed-to pixels valid for the lifetime of the bitmap and then tidying them up when no longer needed (eg. by unpinning, releasing GC handles or freeing non-GC memory) remains with *your* code.

Under normal circumstances, I suspect that `InstallPixels` is the method you probably want to use. `SetPixels` can only do a subset of what `InstallPixels` can, and requires you to deal with memory and lifetime issues yourself.

Answer (score 1):

installpixles installs the pixel into the bitmap for the first time
setpixles sets an already installed pixel to a new value

Comment: ...except the question was about `SetPixels`, not `SetPixel`.

Comment: I know this stack is old, but yes, this answer is not helpful in explaining what "install" actually means in SkiaSharp, ie. does it mean that the data is copied from where the IntPtr points, or is the difference in that it is able to change the representation (width, height, pixel format) of the SKBitmap in addition to what SetPixels does?